# What is the use of decoupling capacitor?

Tags: electronics

I dont understand what does the word "decoupling" mean? Where and Why it is used? Can anyone give me a brief idea>?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quite simply put, it's a little reservoir of energy for a chip or other device to dip into when it needs to get a little extra power.

In Electronics *nothing* happens instantly.  When a chip needs more power it has to get it from the power source.  The power source then has to respond to that by providing more energy, and that then has to make its way down the wires or traces to where it needs to be.

By placing a small capacitor near where the power is consumed the capacitor can respond to that call for more power much faster than the power supply.

Comment: So by responding in that way, I understand that it helps maintain the voltage and provide necessary current to the chip? Am i right?

Comment: Yep, that's right.  Think of it like the tank on your toilet.  You have a local supply of water for flushing, then the normal water supply fills it up slowly afterwards.  You can't flush with just the normal water supply, it's not fast enough.

Comment: What about it's use as a high-frequency transient suppresant or for AC-DC (de)coupling? The term *bypass capacitor* is often interchanged with *decoupling capacitor* so frequently - whether erroneously or not - that it deserves an inclusion, n'est pas?

Comment: That's too technical for an Arduino user.

Comment: @chaaarlie2 You may want to direct that question to the electronics stackexchange, found at [http://electronics.stackexchange.com/](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @Butters The questions were rhetorical; I know the answers, my point was to discover why Majenko omitted two of the three facets of "the decoupling capacitor".

Comment: @Majenko I wouldn't have thought the high-frequency aspect was too technical; it can be explained as succinctly as your existing answer and it is a reasonably fundemental principle. You almost always get two capacitors bundled with each IC on a PCB - one larger electrolytic to act as a power reservoir and one small ceramic job to negate transients. Each is invariably as important as the other, so it's a shame you haven't addressed both.

Comment: @chaaarlie2 The high frequency aspect of the capacitor isn't just down to the capacitor, but the impedance of the traces since the two together form a low-pass filter.  To properly explain that aspect it is necessary to also explain impedance, filters, Q, etc.  Far too much for an Arduino user to cope with.  If they want more detail then they can go to EE.SE where they will get an EE-centric answer covering all those aspects.

Comment: @Majenko And how would the OP know to go to EE.SE for more detail if you fail to mention that these aspects exist?

Comment: @chaaarlie2 If they are capable of understanding the concepts without first undertaking some formal learning they'll already know of the existence of EE.SE and will probably have been there many times before.  If not, and they do want more clarification, then there is this magical thing called "migration" which will send them to EE.SE. In the context of the Arduino, though, just the basics are all that are required. It's enough to know that you DO need decoupling caps, and some rough idea why you need them so you remember to use them. You don't need to know all the quantum mechanics of them.

Comment: @chaaarlie2 IF I were answering this on EE.SE then yes, there would be a huge amount more information.  You have to remember: *this is an arduino site, and people that come here looking for answers generally lack even the most basic knowledge.*  Giving them too much too soon is bad for them.  Look up "Wittgenstein's Ladder", better known by Pratchett fans as "Lies to Children".

Answer (score 1):

Every time a logic circuit switches from a 0 to a 1 or a 1 to a 0, the 1 and 0 transistors are on at the same time for a short period of time.  In MOS circuits, this is combined with the need to charge the gate of the 1 or 0 transistor (Charge is what capacitors store, gates of MOS transistors are capacitors!).

Since all wiring is inductive, the faster the current, the higher the impedance from the main power supply and the switching device (Your processor or sensor etc).  The terms bypass and decoupling mean the same thing:  You are providing a local charge well to supply fast current demands by bypassing the main power system, i.e. supplying current via a different path and thus decoupling the switching device from the inductively isolated main supply.

This is also why we used to use two types of capacitors for decoupling: A 0.1uF ceramic and a 1uF electrolytic for instance...  You couldn't get the whole 1uF in a low resistance ceramic to cover both the Low and High speed transients without paying a lot so you used two or more parts, each covering a portion of the spectrum.  Nowadays a single SMT ceramic with low ESR, low ESL and no lead wires can do the whole job and is usually pretty economical.

Another factor is radiation:  A ringing voltage transient current through inductive wiring acts just like an antenna.